# Shared library between multiple Django projects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

If I have 2 Django apps, how could I share a common library between both? I was thinking about a third library project, that I shortcut to in the other 2 projects locally, & on production replace the shortcut with the whole Library folder. would something like this work? and if so, how would I switch out the shortcut for the actual folder on release?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you want to share code among apps on different servers.

There are 2 methods you can use to achieve that:

1. Publish it to PyPI (Public)
2. Use it from your Github (Private)

**Publishing to PyPI:**

> [Read and follow this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-publish-a-python-package-to-pypi-7be9dd5d6dcd)

**Use it from your github:**

> Follow the above([Publishing to PyPI](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-publish-a-python-package-to-pypi-7be9dd5d6dcd)) article till the publishing
> part. After that follow this [article](http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2013/06/17/sharing-code-across-applications-with-python/#3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use third library as your utility folder and refer code from that. 
Generally, in in project with multiple apps, we create app directory which will be used by other 2 apps a utility.

```
├── app_a
├── app_b
└── common_app
    └── common_utility.py

# and can be imported in app_a and app_b as 
from common_app.common_utility import CommonUtilty
```

Comment: I'm talking about 2 entirely separate projects though - on separate servers, rather than 2 apps.

Comment: okay. I never stumbled on such problem so far. Usually, I would've created common app in both projects. or you can create common_app in project_1 and reference common_app from project_2.